# Simple Concave Function Question

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Suppose we have a function $f:[0,\infty)\longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ that is concave and $a > b>0$. Then given a constant $c>0$ I claim that $f(a+c) - f(a) \le f(b+c) - f(b)$.

If I draw a picture, this statement seems obvious, but I can't seem to find a simple proof to actually show that this is the case!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: i think that the place to start is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function

Comment: I also think that it is more appropriate (in this case) for the OP to show work before being provided an answer.  To the OP: please spend 30 minutes to an hour trying (on scratch paper) to solve the problem.  Then, edit your posting to show your work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** On one hand your inequality is same as $\frac{f(a+c)-f(a)}{c} \leqslant  \frac{f(b+c)-f(b)}{c}$ and on second hand, if concave function have second derivative, then it is non-positive i.e. first derivative is not increasing.

**Addition**.
In more general case, without derivatives, definition of concavity we can rewrite for any $x_1<x<x_2$ as $\frac{f(x)-f(x_1)}{x-x_1} \geqslant \frac{f(x)-f(x_2)}{x_2-x}$.

Comment: the statement is also true when $f$ is not differentiable

Comment: @LinAlg. Added way for not differentiable case to answer.

Comment: it's true, but does not follow from convexity so easily

Comment: @LinAlg. Do you think it will be more good, if I type how to get it? Then hinting part reduced..

Comment: that would be better, but perhaps you should wait for OP to return ;)

Comment: Ok. let's wait reaction on existing.